# Função remove() não deleta o arquivo em C

Tags: c, c++

Estou tentando apagar um arquivo e logo depois renomear um outro arquivo, porém acaba que a função remove não apaga o arquivo. Testei em duas máquinas, dando full permissão, porém sem sucesso. No debug eu recebo a mensagem `permission danied`, porém já dei full permissão. O arquivo que não consigo excluir é o  `puser = fopen("dados\\cad_funcionario.txt", "r")`, eu fecho ele dentro do ultimo while desse código. O que pode ser isso?

```c
    /*DELETE TELAS*/
void deletar_usuario        (void)
{

    int test;
    test = 0;
    
    user* cusuario = calloc(1, sizeof(user)* 1);
    user_del* cusuario_del = calloc(1, sizeof(user_del)* 1);

    puser = fopen("dados\\cad_funcionario.txt", "r");
    if (puser == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n\nErro ao abrir arquivo ou ainda nao foi realizado nenhum cadastro!");
        
        int verificaarq;
        verificaarq = 0;
        printf("\n\nTecle [1] para voltar ao menu principal ou [2] para sair do programa: ");
        scanf("%i", &verificaarq);

        switch (verificaarq)
        {
            case 1 : main_principal();  break;  
            case 2 : exit(0);       
            default:printf("\nMenu inexistente, tente novamente [1] ou [2].");
        }
    }
    
    temporario = fopen("dados\\temporario_user_del.txt", "w");
    if (temporario == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n\nErro ao abrir arquivo ou ainda nao foi realizado nenhum cadastro!");
        
        int verificaarq;
        verificaarq = 0;
        printf("\n\nTecle [1] para voltar ao menu principal ou [2] para sair do programa: ");
        scanf("%i", &verificaarq);

        switch (verificaarq)
        {
            case 1 : main_principal();  break;  
            case 2 : exit(0);       
            default:printf("\nMenu inexistente, tente novamente [1] ou [2].");
        }
    }

    printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
    printf("DELETAR USUARIO CADASTRADO\n\n");

    printf("Para deletar um usuario, insira o CPF do usuario: ");
    tratamento_cpf(cusuario_del->cpf, 11);

    while (fscanf(puser, "%d\n %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n]s", &cusuario->codigo, cusuario->nome, cusuario->celular, cusuario->email, cusuario->cpf, cusuario->usuario, cusuario->senha, cusuario->endereco.estado, cusuario->endereco.cidade, cusuario->endereco.bairro, cusuario->endereco.logradouro, cusuario->endereco.complemento, cusuario->endereco.cep)!=EOF)
    {
        if(strcmp(cusuario->cpf, cusuario_del->cpf) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(temporario, "%i\n", cusuario->codigo);
            fprintf(temporario, "%s\n", cusuario->nome);
            fprintf(temporario, "%s\n", cusuario->celular);
            fprintf(temporario, "%s\n", cusuario->email);
            fprintf(temporario, "%s\n", cusuario->cpf);
            fprintf(temporario, "%s\n", cusuario->usuario);
            fprintf(temporario, "%s\n", cusuario->senha);
            fprintf(temporario, "%s\n", cusuario->endereco.estado);
            fprintf(temporario, "%s\n", cusuario->endereco.cidade);
            fprintf(temporario, "%s\n", cusuario->endereco.bairro);
            fprintf(temporario, "%s\n", cusuario->endereco.logradouro);
            fprintf(temporario, "%s\n", cusuario->endereco.complemento);
            fprintf(temporario, "%s\n", cusuario->endereco.cep);
        }
        else
        {
            test++;
            memset(cusuario->senha, 0, sizeof(cusuario->senha));
            printf("\n\nCodigo: %i\nNome: %s\nCelular: %.2s-%.5s-%.4s\nE-mail: %s\nCPF: %.3s.%.3s.%.3s-%.2s\nUsuario no sistema: %s\nSenha: %s\nEstado: %s\nCidade: %s\nBairro: %s\nlogradouro: %s\nComplemento: %s\nCep: %.5s-%.3s\n", cusuario->codigo, cusuario->nome, cusuario->celular, cusuario->celular+2, cusuario->celular+7, cusuario->email, cusuario->cpf, cusuario->cpf+3, cusuario->cpf+6, cusuario->cpf+9, cusuario->usuario, cusuario->senha, cusuario->endereco.estado, cusuario->endereco.cidade, cusuario->endereco.bairro, cusuario->endereco.logradouro, cusuario->endereco.complemento, cusuario->endereco.cep, cusuario->endereco.cep+5);
        }
    }

    while((cusuario->salvar != 1 || cusuario->salvar != 2) && test == 0)
    {
        printf("\n\n\nNao ha registros com esse CPF!\n\n"); 
        printf("\n\nTecle [1] para tentar novamente ou [2] para VOLTAR ao menu de cadastro: ");
        scanf("%i", &cusuario->salvar);

        if (cusuario->salvar == 1 || cusuario->salvar == 2)
        {
            fclose(puser);
            fclose(temporario);
        }
        switch (cusuario->salvar)
        {
            case 1 : deletar_usuario(); break;  
            case 2 : main_delete(); break;
            default:printf("\nOpcao inexistente, tente novamente [1] ou [2]."); 
        }
    }

    while(cusuario->salvar != 1 || cusuario->salvar != 2)
    {
        printf("\n\nTecle [1] para confirmar a EXCLUSAO desse usuario ou [2] para VOLTAR ao menu de cadastro: ");
        scanf("%i", &cusuario->salvar);

        switch (cusuario->salvar)
        {
            case 1 : break; 
            case 2 : main_delete(); break;
            default:printf("\nOpcao inexistente, tente novamente [1] ou [2]."); 
        }
        
        fclose(puser);
        fclose(temporario); 
        
        remove("dados\\cad_funcionario.txt");
        int rem = 0;
        rem = remove("dados\\cad_funcionario.txt");
        if (rem == 0)
        {
                        rename("dados\\temporario_user_del.txt", "dados\\cad_funcionario.txt");
            printf("O arquivo foi deletado com sucesso!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            remove("dados\\temporario_user_del.txt");
            perror("Nao foi possivel deletar o arquivo!");
            system("pause");
        }

        

        printf("Tecle ENTER para voltar ao menu anterior!");
        getchar();
        main_delete();
    }           
}
```

Comment: O erro está ocorrendo na segunda vez que você remove o arquivo?

Comment: O erro só ocorre ao tentar remover o remove("dados\\cad_funcionario.txt");

já o remove("dados\\temporario_user_del.txt"); que está dentro do else, é removido normalmente.

Comment: Seu código tem duas vezes `remove("dados\\cad_funcionario.txt");`.

Comment: um é a variável recebendo o valor, mas eu testei deixando somente o remove("dados\\cad_funcionario.txt");, sem o rem = remove("dados\\cad_funcionario.txt");

porém não adiantou!

Comment: Ele não remove o arquivo de jeito nenhum, nem no primeiro  nem no segundo.

Comment: O sistema que você usa é qual ? Windows ? O arquivo já existia à prioria ou foi criado no código ?

Comment: Boa tarde colega, Já consegui resolver esse problema, coloquei os fclose fora do while, assim que termina a consulta, e deu certo, vlw pelo apoio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

como um axioma da programação, recomendo que feche o arquivo no mesmo escopo em que foi aberto, a menos que você execute um "do {} white (...)" não há certeza de que o fclose será chamado...

e se você estiver compilado para windows, rename não irá funcionar, invés disto, no windows use:

```
#include <fileapi.h>
MoveFileA(char*,char*)
ou
MoveFileW(wchar*,wchar*)
```

apesar de declarado, no windows não é funcional, assim como outras funções que usadas para enumerar arquivos de uma pasta, e o próprio remove (no caso de diretórios).

*obs.: se achar que está faltando algo no arquivo... pode ser um sinal, que você esqueceu ele aberto, as vezes as ultimas alterações em um arquivo que não foi fechado não são salvas.